# for of loop continuing even on async/await even before the response

Tags: asynchronous, promise, async-await, for-of-loop

Below is my code snippet which has async calls with await.

```
let reccData = [] 

for (const uniformId of uniformCollectionIds) {
     let watchCreatives = await CreativeCollection.findById(uniformId);

     if(watchCreatives.isActive){
             let recommendations = await ReccService.fetchReccSeries(watchCreatives.reccNo);
             if(recommendations){
                  reccData.push({reccNo:recommendations.reccNo, watchList:recommendations.watchListId,...})
             } 
     }
}

Logistics.insertMany(reccData).then(() => {
    //My other business logic goes here
 });
```

ReccService.ts

```
public fetchReccSeries = async (reccNo:number) => {
    let getRecc = await Recc.findByNumber(reccNo)
    if(getRecc){
      return getRecc 
    }
};
```

The problem with the above code is, even before i get the response from `await ReccService.fetchReccSeries` the `for..of` moves to the next iteration. Above is just a code snippet, and the reason i want it to execute in a sequential way is, a lot of counter/incremental logic is based on that.

**What i tried**

A `.then({})` promise confirmation, but still the it behaves the same way.

Prepending `await` to `for..of`

```
for await (const uniformId of uniformCollectionIds) {
```

Trying `Promise.All` is out of my scope

**What I'm expecting:**

Until all the execution inside each iteration is not done, the next for iteration should not invoke

Comment: Your `fetchReccSeries` code is fine. What does `Recc.findByNumber` return? How do you know when you "get the response"?

Comment: @Bergi Recc.findByNumber returns a single record from a collection. Recc is a mongoose model.

Comment: @Bergi findByNumber returns a single record from collection. Recc is a mongoose model.